# Calculate the surrounding rect of a polygon

Tags: javascript, math

Not math savvy here!

I need a function that, receiving an array of coords ([[0,1],[1,1]...]) defining a closed polygon, calculates the width and height of the surrounding rect.

Here's what I have:

```js
function calculateSurroundingRect(coords) {
  let minX = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
  let maxX = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER
  let minY = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER
  let maxY = Number.MIN_SAFE_INTEGER

  for (let i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
    const [x1, y1] = coords[i]
    minX = Math.min(minX, x1)
    maxX = Math.max(maxX, x1)
    minY = Math.min(minY, y1)
    maxY = Math.max(maxY, y1)
  }

  return [maxX - minX, maxY - minY]
}

const polygon = [
    [
        6.161386730424397,
        50.80326113479265
    ],
    [
        5.601912731619848,
        51.036655126728135
    ],
    [
        4.970711297071148,
        51.47843661146317
    ],
    [
        4.05260011954573,
        51.27004911866362
    ],
    [
        3.3209802749551898,
        51.34506861607147
    ],
    [
        3.8374178123132197,
        51.62014010656685
    ],
    [
        4.712492528392119,
        53.09552355558759
    ],
    [
        6.075313807531387,
        53.51229854118668
    ],
    [
        6.907352062163795,
        53.47895654233875
    ],
    [
        7.093843395098645,
        53.14553655385947
    ],
    [
        6.849970113568446,
        52.22863158554151
    ],
    [
        6.591751344889417,
        51.85353409850234
    ],
    [
        5.989240884638377,
        51.85353409850234
    ],
    [
        6.161386730424397,
        50.80326113479265
    ]
    ];

console.log(calculateSurroundingRect(polygon));
```

But for some reason I'm not getting the desired rect. Any clues?
I think I may doing something wrong related the coordinate system. As the width/height seems to be reverse.

[image]

Comment: So, what's the problem? At a first glance, your code seems ok to me (at least if the polygon is convex). Include in the code the example polygon that fails and the expected result.

Comment: _“I think I may doing something wrong related the coordinate system.”_ — Maybe. How are these shapes drawn? How is the canvas defined? Please show a [mre] (in an [edit]) of how you get this result.

Comment: It looks OK to me https://ibb.co/vYYC6Rs, what result did you expect?

Comment: looks perfectly fine... thanks for elaborating a example... probably the problem is related to the rendering